# execute stored procedure in remote server with variable names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a cursor and its fetching database name and linked server name to execute a procedure in each of them

```
Declare getDBLinkServer cursor for  
select DatabaseName, LinkServerName from DBnLinkServer  
Open getDBLinkServer  
fetch next from getDBLinkServer into @DatabaseName, @LinkServerName  
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
Begin  
    exec @LinkServerName.@DatabaseName.dbo.someProcedure 'some' 
    fetch next from getDBLinkServer into @DatabaseName, @LinkServerName  
End  
Close getDBLinkServer  
Deallocate getDBLinkServer
```

This is showing `Incorrect syntax near '.'` How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic sql. Like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'exec ' + @LinkServerName + '.' + @DatabaseName + '.dbo.'+@someProcedure+' ''some''' 

exec sp_executeSQL @sql
```